# R - looping through the values of a column that has a dot in its name

Tags: r, for-loop, while-loop

I'm learning the very basics of the R language.

I would like to loop (with either a loop or a while function since that's what I'm learning) through all the values of a specific dataset column that is called "Kid.Height". Let's say the dataset is called test.

I can target a standard column like this : "test$KidHeight". But not with a dot in its name ("test$Kid.Height").

I would like to do something like this:

```
for(i in test$Kid.Height) {
    print(Kid.Height.value);
}
```

So that I can read all the row values of that column

I can't find any instance on the web that tells me how to deal with dots in columns name.
I know how to target a column by its index but not by name so that it always works, however fancy it is.

PS: since I'm learning the basics, if I can ask you the most clean and recommended way to achieve this, so that I can learn from scratch, I would be grateful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Columns can also be accessed using square brackets for difficult column names, try:

```
test['Kid.Height']
```